# Vue custom components works locally but not on the server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-s3

I have a SPA built with Vue.js. The custom components render/update wihtout any issue on the local machine but not after I deployed to the server. The Vue app has no backend codes, just frontend, we deployed to AWS S3 bucket. The local sever I'm running is using npm run serve. I have done custom components and deployed to S3 bucket before, all of them works without any issues. Does anyone have the same issues?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you deployed to the bucket? And does the page load at all? Any error messages?

Comment: Yes. When we build the app, we run the build command and everything will be packed into one folder and that contains all the files we need to be hosted using S3 bucket. Then I just need to upload all the files in the folder to S3 bucket. And I got no errors, the page renders fine except the custom components. One of the custom input renders fine but it lost all the functionalities.

Comment: " The local sever I'm running is using npm run serve" - you're comparing oranges to apples. You need to build it and run with webserver, e.g `http-server`

Comment: Or build it with vue-cli-service: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary

Comment: I did use vue-cli-service-build

Comment: the problem here is i used the same build and it worked before, now it's not working with the new custom components. And these new custom components work without issues on the localhost.

Comment: After long hours of troubleshooting, I found the problem. It's because I replaced the <v-app> tag with regular <div> tag because I want to get rid of vuetify styles, I'm trying to rewrite this app without the vuetify styles. Is it possible to not use <v-app>? It works perfectly in local server without vuetify.